# DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator working

Tags: spring

How DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator works in Spring?.

How it know on which class(target class on which advice is to run) do i have to run the advice?

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator" />
```